# How do you change the default TERM value set at console login (Ubuntu)?

Tags: bash, shell, console, xterm

The $TERM shell value in Ubuntu defaults to "xterm" for a console login. How can I change it so it defaults to "xterm-color"? I'm asking because it looks like this is the easiest way to turn-on the color prompt.

I am aware you can reset the TERM value in the .bashrc or other login script, but I'd rather just force the TERM value to a more reasonable default.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe need to check this. It's possible this was an SSH login and not the console. Any pointers would be good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *TERM* variable stores the name of an entry in the *terminfo* database that helps the OS determine how to display information to your terminal.  What it defaults to depends entirely on how you've logged in.

---

Usually, "the console" means you're physically at the computer, logging into one of the text-based virtual terminals (VT1-6).

- *TERM* defaults to *linux* (this may differ between distributions; *vt100* is a safe alternative)

  - To change this, on Ubuntu 9.10, you'll need to tweak the *getty* command defined in */etc/init/tty1.conf*.  That will change the setting for */dev/tty1* (VT1), and you'll need to make the same changes in */etc/init/tty2.conf*, *..tty3.conf*, etc to get the other virtual terminals as well.

    ```
    # original getty command in /etc/init/tty1.conf
    exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1

    # new command; sets default TERM on /dev/tty1 to "foobar"
    exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1 foobar
    ```

---

If you're logged into X/Gnome/KDE (VT7, 8, or 9), you're not using a console, at least in this context.  Technically this is logging into X and using a *pseudo-terminal* via a *terminal emulator* application -- that's what gives you the window that shows your shell & commandline.

- *TERM* is initially set by your terminal emulator.  It can be modified in your shell startup files (*~/.bashrc*, *~/.profile*, etc).

  - *xterm*, *rxvt*, *xterm-color*, *xterm-256color* are all common values
  - To change this value, consult the documentation for your terminal emulator.  For example, if using *rxvt-unicode* (aka *urxvt*), you'd use the `-tn termname` commandline option.

---

If you're logged in remotely (via SSH or remote X), you're definitely not using a console in any context; again, you're using a *pseudo-terminal*.

- *TERM* is inherited by the program that started SSH:

  - SSH from a linux virtual terminal results in a remote *TERM* of *linux*;
  - SSH from a commandline in an X-windows terminal emulator results in a remote *TERM* of whatever *TERM* was set to prior to the SSH command;
  - SSH from a Windows system using PuTTY defaults to *xterm*, but this can be changed in PuTTY's configuration;
  - and any of the above settings can be overridden by the shell startup files of the remote user.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of good info here:

```
man 7 term
```

> A default TERM value will be set on a
>   per-line basis by either /etc/inittab
>   (Linux and System-V-like  UNIXes)  or
>   /etc/ttys  (BSD UNIXes).  This will
>   nearly always suffice for workstation
>   and microcomputer consoles.

The next problem is that Ubuntu 9.10 does not have `/etc/inittab` or `/etc/ttys`.

```
man inittab
```

> The  Upstart  init(8) daemon does not
>   use this file, and instead reads its
>   configuration from files in /etc/init.
>   See init(5) for more details.

Looking into /etc/init, you can find the tty*.conf files. They are run by exec'ing getty. So then:

```
man getty
```

> **term**   The  value  to be used for the TERM environment variable.
>   This overrides whatever init(8) may
>   have set, and is inherited by login and the shell.

This is good info. Now we know that the default TERM value comes from init(8)

... after all this I didn't manage to figure out how to change the default TERM value used by init.

Comment: that manpage quote describes setting TERM when logged in on "the console"; Ubuntu uses *upstart* instead of the older *init*, and defines *tty1* etc in files like */etc/init/tty1.conf*